# Configuring YUM for updates from Mirrored Repo

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I've got a weird situation where I have to mirror my RHEL 7 repos to other RHEL7 systems.  I followed the RHN documentation at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016#basic on creating the mirrors on my server (using `reposync` and `createrepo`).  I've configured Apache and can use a web browser to access each repo at `http://server_name/repo_name/repodata/repomd.xml`.

However, when I do `yum update` from my client server, I get the two error messages

```
*http://server_name/repo_name/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found*
*failure: repodata/repomd.xml from repo_name: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try*
```

A proxy isn't needed, though I have configured /etc/yum.conf with and without the proxy and it doesn't make a difference.  I appreciate people taking the time to review my problem.

The repo file on my failing client looks like this;

```
[repo_name]
name=repo_name
baseurl=http://server_name/repo_name/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
sslverify=0
```

The repo directory tree on my server looks like this;

```
/web root
  repo_name
    Packages
    repodata
      repomd.xml
      updateinfo.xml
      various xml.gz files too
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird proxy issues was causing issues. It shouldn't have been ignoring the proxy and it was not.